# Header and Paragraph slides down and Glyphicon is placed a bit above input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

This my webpage code being made as a mobile version (doesn't matter).

Problem is that **when I try to enter password**, **the h1,p stuff slides down** a bit. And **glyphicon is above the input** box.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/src/favicon.ico?">
    <title>InfoHub- SE Comps
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/jquery.fullPage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/examples.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (screen.width <= 700) {
            window.location = "http://m.codearena.me/courses";
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        h1 {
            font-size: 7em;
            font-family: arial, helvetica;
            color: #fff;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .section {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .intro p {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 40px;
        }
        .form-control {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #header,
        #footer {
            position: fixed;
            height: 75px;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            background: #333;
            z-index: 9;
            text-align: center;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            padding-top: 20px;
            font-size: 28px;
        }
        #header {
            top: 0px;
        }
        #footer {
            bottom: 0px;
        }
        #infoMenu {
            bottom: 80px;
        }
        #infoMenu li a {
            color: #fff;
            z-index: 999;
        }
        #hidden {
            display: none;
        }
        .alert {
            display: none;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #f00;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/scrolloverflow.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery.fullPage.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/examples.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-83360384-1', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                anchors: ['homepage'],
                sectionsColor: ['#285877'],
                css3: true,
                scrollOverflow: true,
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-53HK2L" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
    </noscript>
    <script>
        (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
            w[l] = w[l] || [];
            w[l].push({
                'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
                event: 'gtm.js'
            });
            var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j = d.createElement(s),
                dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
            j.async = true;
            j.src =
                '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
        })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-53HK2L');
    </script>
    <div id="header">Website is working slow, because of encryption on 02 October.</div>
    <div id="footer">
        <text style="position: relative;bottom: 17px;">
            Made by SiDd
            <br>
            <a href="http://siddheshpatil.me" style="color:white;text-align: center">siddheshpatil.me
        </a>
            <text>
    </div>
    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section " id="section0">
            <div class="intro">
                <h1>InfoHub
              </h1>
                <p id="message">Ask administrator for password.</p>
                <br>
                <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                    <div id="hide" style="width: 300px;margin:0 auto;" class="form-group ">
                        <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput" style="font-size:30px">Enter password:</label>
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" ng-model='passwd' ng-change='change()' id="focusedInput" type="password" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('button').click()">
                        <span id="glyp"></span>
                        <br>
                        <button id="button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="myfunction()">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script>
                    function myfunction() {
                        if (document.getElementById('focusedInput').value == 'promocode') {
                            document.getElementById('hidden').classList.toggle('show');
                            document.getElementById('hide').style.display = 'none';
                        } else {
                            alert('Invalid password!')
                        }
                    }
                </script>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    //<![CDATA[

                    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
                        $scope.change = function() {
                            if ($scope.passwd == "promocode") {
                                document.getElementById('hide').className = 'form-group has-success has-feedback input-lg';
                                document.getElementById('glyp').className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback fa-lg';
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById('hide').className = 'form-group has-error has-feedback input-lg';
                                document.getElementById('glyp').className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback fa-lg';
                            }
                        };
                    });
                    //]]>
                </script>
            </div>
            <div id="hidden">
                <button id="button2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="location.href='https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B9dT7x_mr4cJTUpRUnQtRmZhU3M?usp=sharing';">Go to paid courses</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am not at all able to solve this in any way. Please help me solve it. It is super duper hard for me to solve. I am a newbie. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One wonders what all the unclosed and invalid `<text>` elements are for ?

Comment: Why are you adding the class `input-lg` to the `#hide` div? This is the class that is adding padding. Just remove `input-lg` from line 171 and 174 (170 and 173 in the code you send us --the first line with the `<html>` tag is missing).

Comment: A live link would be usefull here.

Comment: Yes, really need to see the website as you have css & js linked locally.